# Rivets.js if binder function call

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, custom-data-attribute, rivets.js

I was attempting to use the default binder that comes with rivets.js , if and unless and wanting to evaluate return value from a dom element.

HTML

```
<div id="elem" custom-attribute="false">
    <h1 rv-if="testing.getAttribute('custom-attribute')">Testing </h1>
</div>
```

JS

```
rivets.bind(document, testing: document.getElementbyId(elem);
```

What is the best way to access a custom boolean attribute from a dom element to evaluate for a rivets if binder? Do I have to implement a custom binder?

I also did this but I hear that this is very frowned upon practice

```
document.getElementbyId("elem").customAttr=false;
rivets.bind(document, testing: document.getElementbyId(elem);
```

and then in the HTML

```
 <div id="elem" custom-attribute="false">
    <h1 rv-if="testing.customAttr">Testing </h1>
</div>
```

the below approach works, but what exactly is the con to setting attributes on an element in this manner and what is the best way to use data attributes the standard way with rivets default if and unless binders>

Comment: Why is it mandatory to read the boolean from DOM?  instead of `document.getElementbyId("elem").customAttr=false;
rivets.bind(document, testing: document.getElementbyId(elem);` why not just do: `rivets.bind(document, flag: false` why do you need pass an element like this...? You should use custom binders to access elements

Comment: The reason is because in the application there are multiple instances of a dynamically generated dom element, elements which we track references to, in order to modify/delete later on. If we use rivets.bind with a custom flag, then we would also have to keep track of the rivets binding reference. We would then end up with two variables to manage what is essentially one entity, for a large amount of entities. What's a better way?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you want to keep reference to rivets binding..? If you have to, why is it not necessary in your original approach..?!